# Why doesn't bash exit after command not found?

Tags: bash, shell, centos

When I run a command which doesn't exist:

```
[root@centos2 ~]# abc
bash: abc: command not found...
^C
[root@centos2 ~]#
```

Bash doens't exit (I waited for at least 30 seconds) immediately. I have to sent <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to exit.

It is normal when I run other commands:

```
[root@centos2 ~]# echo 'a'
a
[root@centos2 ~]#
```

I'm running on CentOS 8:

```
[root@centos2 ~]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5) (GCC)) #1 SMP Wed Jun 10 11:09:32 UTC 2020
[root@centos2 ~]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)
```

Comment: What is the output of `declare -pf command_not_found_handle`? Does the problem persist after `unset -f command_not_found_handle`?

Comment: The linked question has answers with solutions. The delay can extend to several minutes if the package caches need refreshing.